# Present Modal from Segmented View

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How are you supposed to present a new view from a segmented control view?

When I try:

```
let newViewController = NewViewController()
self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I receive an error:

```
myApp[39142:611263] [Presentation] Attempt to present <myApp.NewViewController: 0x7fb6a2051000> on <myApp.SegmentedViewOneTableViewController: 0x7fb6a1d2dd50> (from <myApp.SegmentedViewOneTableViewController: 0x7fb6a1d2dd50>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
```

But the view is loaded via the segmented view control. Am I loading something incorrectly here?

This is a wireframe of the view setup, and I'm clicking the edit action on the table row, and want to load up a new view controller to edit that row.

[image: Segmented View One Visible]

Comment: `self` is a `SegmentedViewOneTableViewController`. It's not on screen yet, so it can't present `newViewController` (of type `NewViewController`).

Comment: @Larme I added a wireframe to help understand. But how can the `SegmentedViewOneTableViewController` not be on the screen yet, when its literally what I'm interacting with to trigger a table action?

Comment: Because you are using another instance? Your created a new object of type `SegmentedViewOneTableViewController` and that's not the one on screen, and it's the one who is calling `present()`. But since it's not the one on screen (in view hierarchy)... ?

Answer (score 1):

@Larme So you got me to a solution. I needed to wrap my UIView's in UIViewControllers that made up the Segment Control children views . The Table View, while present wasn't actually part of the window hierarchy in a way that would allow me to present a modal view.

The following result basically allowed me to get it to work:

```
self.addChild(self.segmentViewOnViewController)
self.segmentViewOnViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame
view.addSubview(self.segmentViewOnViewController.view)
self.segmentViewOnViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

From there, instead of adding the `segmentOneViewContainer` to `self.view`, I added it to `self.segmentViewOnViewController`